# GET manifest endpoint is returning 401

Tags: autodesk-viewer

My Forge viewer code hits the [GET manifest endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) to extract Navisworks saved viewpoints. This script had been working until a few days ago, and now it is returning a 401 Unauthorized. I cannot identify any changes I have made to my code that would have caused this to happen. The token and urn are valid for viewing the model.

Comment: generally, 401 means the token expires or is invalid to access this manifest. I did a quick test, this endpoint works well with returning the saved viewpoints data of a Navisworks file. Could you firstly try with simpler tool such as Curl or Postman to check if the manifest can work? In addition, in your script, please check if the workflow of token is correct, or if the manifest happened to other bucket which this client key has not access anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I had another script interfering that caused my urn to become undefined. After fixing this it worked